# Extended Text for applying ellipses in middle for text widget

Tags: flutter, text, widget, overflow

I have a Text widget with styling and decoration. Currently I can make the overflow text as ellipses at end. But I want to add ellipses in the middle. I found this library [`extended_text`](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text). But this takes a widget by default and then a child widget in the overflowWidget. How am I supposed to use it properly? Can someone help me out?

`Text(text, overflow: textOverflow, style: style.copyWith( color: color, fontWeight: fontWeight, decoration: underlined ? TextDecoration.underline : null));`

I have to convert the above widget into extended widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example of [extended_text](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text), you can easily convert your current `Text` widget into `ExtendedText` using the following example.

```
ExtendedText(
  'This is a very loooooooooooooooooooongggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg text',
  maxLines: 1,
  style: TextStyle(                // <<Your current text style go here
      color: Colors.black,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      decoration: TextDecoration.underline
  ),
  overflowWidget: TextOverflowWidget(
    position: TextOverflowPosition.middle, //   << start/middle/end
    child: Text(
      ".....",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        decoration: TextDecoration.underline
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

`TextOverflowPosition.middle`
[image]

`TextOverflowPosition.start`
[image]

`TextOverflowPosition.end`
[image]

Comment: It is adding 1 character space on either side of the ellipses. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: I have updated the answer. The idea is to try to match the style of the `Text("...")` with the main `Text` style.